# How to maintain two custom cells in one tableview with segment selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am new to iOS. I have one `UIViewController` in that added one tableview and segmented control. If I press the segmented value = 0, I want to the first custom cell with loading images and title and segment value = 1, I want to display my second custom cell with `UICollectionView` with loading of images and title, how can I do that please help me? Here is some of my code:

MenuViewController.m

```
-(void)callSegmentSelected
{
value=(int)segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://API"];
NSString *jsonString = @"";
NSData *myJSONData =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myJSONData]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if(str.length > 0)
{
    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]);
    listBannerArray =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    [progressHud hide:YES];
    [self.tableViewContest reloadData];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
}
```

Here is my CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
 MenuTableViewCell *cell = (MenuTableViewCell *)[tableViewContest dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
 if (cell == nil)
{
NSArray * myNib;
myNib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MenuTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = (MenuTableViewCell *)[myNib lastObject];
}
if(value == 0)
{
@try
{
    if((NSNull *)[[listBannerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"listbanner"] != [NSNull null])
    {
        if([[[listBannerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"listbanner"] length] > 0)
        {
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[listBannerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"listbanner"]];
            [cell.listBanner sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilepic_bg"]];
        }
        else
        {
        }                
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
}
if((NSNull *)[[listBannerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"examtitle"] != [NSNull null])
{
    if([[[listBannerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"examtitle"] length] > 0)
    {
        cell.examTitle.text = [[listBannerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"examtitle"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.examTitle.text = @"Data Error";
    }
}
else
{
    cell.examTitle.text = @"Data Error";
}
}
```

When Click on SegmentIndex=0 Screen like this

[image]

When Click on SegmentIndex=1 like this

[image]

Comment: can you show your segemnt action

Comment: for segmented value=0 display tableview with custom cell & for segmented value=1 display collectionView with custom cell,  right?

Comment: then on segmented value=0 display tableview and hide collectionview & on segmented value = 1 display collectionview and hide tableview reload unhidden view when segment click

Comment: See my Updated Question @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `enum` for differentiate the segment action.

Step 1 : Create the enum for the selection.

```
typedef enum {
   OPTION_FIRST = 0,
   OPTION_SECOND
} SEGMENT_SELECTION;
```

Step 2 : On your MenuViewController.m

1) Create the instance of `SEGMENT_SELECTION`

> @property(nonatomic) SEGMENT_SELECTION segmentSelection;

2) Assign the value to `segmentSelection`

```
-(void)callSegmentSelected
{
  if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    segmentSelection = OPTION_FIRST
  else
    segmentSelection = OPTION_SECOND

    [self.tableViewContest reloadData];//For update the content in tableview
}
```

Step 3 : Write the below code on CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(segmentSelection == OPTION_FIRST) {
      //Load the content of FIRST segment action 
    }
    else {
      //Load the content of SECOND segment action
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.